# How do I add another tab on my navigation bar without it wrapping to the next line?

Tags: css, menu, navigationbar

My navigation bar is centered but and wraps the tabs of the navigation bar to the next line if I try to add a 6th tab.

I am working on this webpage specifically, but have the same problem on other parts of this site too. http://ventricular.org/CORTICALEVOLUTION2018/corticalevolution2018.html

It does this in Safari, but not Chrome.

```css
nav{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 display:block;
 height:40px;
}

nav ul li{
 display:block;
 width:16%;
 float:left;
 text-align:center; 
}

nav ul li a{
 font-family: Candara;
 width:90%;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:400;
 line-height:250%;
 display:block;
 color:#9933cc;
}

nav ul li a:hover{
 color:#9933cc;
}

nav ul li p{
 font-family: Candara;
 width:90%;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 font-weight:400;
 line-height:250%;
 display:block;
 color:#9933cc;
}
```

```html
        <nav> <!-- Navigation Start -->
            <ul>
             <li><a href="corticalevolution2018.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="speakers.html">SPEAKERS</a></li>
                <li><a href="sponsors.html">SPONSORS</a></li>
                <li><a href="2018_Conference_Photos.html">PHOTOS</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ventricular.org">VENTRICULAR.ORG</a></li>
                
            </ul>      
        </nav> <!-- Navigation End -->
    </div><!--/top-->
    
    
    <hr/><!-- Horizontal Line -->
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question will all relevant code needed to reproduce your situation (a [mcve]). You can likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: What browser and what size screen?  I can't reproduce the issue on your site.

Comment: Happens in Safari, not chrome. I added a snippet (I think!). Thank you so much.

Comment: My screen is 20''.